# Entity Framework - Fluent APi - Create table with 2 FK

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, ef-code-first, ef-fluent-api

I have this product class which has a list of products associated.

eg:

Product = StarWar

AssociatedProducts = Episode V: The Empire Strikes Back,                        Episode VI: Return of the Jedi, Episode VII: The Force Awakens

But EF generates the database with some extra columns.

This is my Product Class:

```
public class Product 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string ShortDescription { get; set; }
    public string FullDescription { get; set; }
    public decimal UnitPrice { get; set; }
    ......
    public virtual ICollection<AssociatedProducts> AssociatedProducts { get; set; }
    ......
}
```

This is my AssociatedProduct Class:

```
public class AssociatedProducts
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public int AssociatedProductId { get; set; }

    public int DisplayOrder { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }

    public virtual Product Products { get; set; }
    public virtual Product AssociatedProductsId { get; set; }
}
```

This is my mapping for AssocietedProduct class:

```
public AssociatedProductsMap()
    {
        // Primary Key
        HasKey(a => a.Id);

        // Properties
        Property(a => a.CreatedOn).IsRequired();
        Property(a => a.ProductId).IsRequired();
        Property(a => a.AssociatedProductId).IsRequired();
        Property(a => a.DisplayOrder).IsRequired();

        //Relationship
        HasRequired(a => a.Products)
            .WithMany(p => p.Products)
            .HasForeignKey(a => a.ProductId)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

        HasRequired(a => a.AssociatedProductsId)
            .WithMany(p => p.AssociatedProducts)
            .HasForeignKey(a => a.AssociatedProductId)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

        //Table  
        ToTable("AssociatedProducts");
    }
```

And this is how I am seeding:

```
var associetedProducts = new List<AssociatedProducts>
        {
            new AssociatedProducts {ProductId= 1, AssociatedProductId = 3, DisplayOrder = 1, CreatedOn = DateTime.Now},
            new AssociatedProducts {ProductId= 1, AssociatedProductId = 4, DisplayOrder = 2, CreatedOn = DateTime.Now},
            new AssociatedProducts {ProductId= 1, AssociatedProductId = 5, DisplayOrder = 3, CreatedOn = DateTime.Now}
        }

new List<Product>
        {
          new Product {Name = "StarWar", ShortDescription = "...", FullDescription = "P.......", UnitPrice = 15m, AssociatedProducts = associetedProducts},
          new Product {Name = "StarWar Episode V", ShortDescription = "...", FullDescription = "P.......", UnitPrice = 15m},
          new Product {Name = "StarWar Episode VI", ShortDescription = "...", FullDescription = "P.......", UnitPrice = 15m},
          new Product {Name = "StarWar Episode VII", ShortDescription = "...", FullDescription = "P.......", UnitPrice = 15m},
    }.ForEach(a => context.Products.AddOrUpdate(a));

context.SaveChanges();
```

This is what I expect from AssociatedProductsId Table:
ID + ProductId (FK) + AssociatedProductsId(FK) + date + ......

[image]

But this is what I get:
[image]

What is my mistake ?
Is this a good way to associate a product ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your classes are not right.

1 Problem: Why EF generates the table with extra columns?

In that case EF is using TPH strategy. Take a look at this link http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alexj/archive/2009/04/15/tip-12-choosing-an-inheritance-strategy.aspx

2 Problem: What is my mistake ? Is this a good way to associate a product ?

Your mapping should be something like this:

```
public class Product
{
    public int ProductId { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<ProductAssociation> AssociatedProducts { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<ProductAssociation> ProductsAssociatedThisProduct { get; set; }
}

public class ProductAssociation
{
    public int ProductId { get; set; }

    public int ProductAssociatedId { get; set; }

    public DateTime CreationDate { get; set; }

    public virtual Product Product { get; set; }

    public virtual Product ProductAssociated { get; set; }
}

public class Context : DbContext
{
    public Context() : base("Model2")
    {

    }

    public DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ProductAssociation> ProductsAssociations { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Product>()
            .HasKey(i => i.ProductId);

        modelBuilder.Entity<ProductAssociation>()
            .HasKey(i => new {i.ProductId, i.ProductAssociatedId });

        modelBuilder.Entity<Product>()
            .HasMany(i => i.AssociatedProducts)
            .WithRequired(i => i.ProductAssociated)
            .HasForeignKey(i => i.ProductAssociatedId)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Product>()
            .HasMany(i => i.ProductsAssociatedThisProduct)
            .WithRequired(i => i.Product)
            .HasForeignKey(i => i.ProductId)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);


        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }


}
```

Seed

```
var product1 = new Product() { Name = "StarWars", ProductId = 1 };

var product2 = new Product() { Name = "StarWars II", ProductId = 2 };

context.ProductsAssociations.AddOrUpdate(new ProductAssociation { Product = product1, CreationDate = DateTime.Now, ProductAssociated = product2 });
context.Products.AddOrUpdate(product1);
context.Products.AddOrUpdate(product2);
context.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Hi @Fabio Luz, thank you very much, I made some changes at my code and I got very close, the only problem that I have is that the Id for the table ProductAssociation is not being auto-incremented although this table does not really need an auto-increment column. By the way I could see you are Brazilian like, so Obrigado pela ajuda.

Comment: @Fernando.M the table ProductAssociation has a composite primary key. O ProductId é a FK a qual a associação pertence, o ProductAssociatedId  é a FK do produto a qual está sendo associado... a PK da ProductAssociation é representado por essas duas colunas, por isso nenhum delas devem ser auto-increment, umas vez que ambas são PK e FK

Comment: Sim, o auto-increment seria uma coluna chamada Id, ProductId  e ProductAssociatedId sao 2 FK a parte, mas como eu disse no comentário acima uma coluna ID auto-increment não seria necessario.

Comment: Minha curiosidade é se eu realmente quisesse uma coluna chamada Id como PK, como eu procederia, já que ate então HasKey(a => a.Id); era suficiente para criar a PK.

Comment: Sim, mas essa coluna nao pode existir porque senão 1 produto poderia ser relacionado com outro produto mais de uma vez... o que não seria correto, certo? por isso as pk é ProductId e ProductAssociatedId. Mas caso vc realmente quisesse uma coluna nova como pk e auto-increment seria assim: `.HasKey(a => a.Id);`  `.Property(i => i.Id).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);`

Comment: Certo Fabio, muito obrigado :)