# Defining linked entites with POCO classes

Tags: linq, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I work with EF Code First classes.

I have an entity named `Request`:

```
public class Request
{
    [Key]
    public virtual int RequestID { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

I need to link `Request` each other.

**For example:**

IF we have the 2 links defined below:

- RequestID 1 is linked to RequestID 2
- RequestID 1 is linked to RequestID 3

THEN...

If we ask which requests are linked:

- (A) for 1 : the result is 2,3
- (B) for 2 : the result is 1,3
- (C) For 3 : the result is 1,2

**Explanations:**

- For (A) this is easy to find the result because the link is "direct"
- For (B) and (C) this is a little more complex because the link is retrieved by following the 'path' through 1. I don't know if I'm clear.

**My question:** what is the best way for defining the link model class? After that, how to query (LINQ) these model classes to retrieve results as showed above?

At first, I thought the link model class as below: (don't know if this is a good idea)

```
public class RequestLinked
{
    [Key, Column(Order = 0)]
    [ForeignKey("Request")]
    public int RequestID { get; set; }

    [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
    [ForeignKey("RequestRelated")]
    public int RequestRelatedID { get; set; }

    public virtual Request Request { get; set; }
    public virtual Request RequestRelated { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following structure might be what you are looking for:

Entity

```
public class Request
{
    [Key]
    public virtual int RequestID { get; set; }
    ...
    // Suppose that "1" is related to "2" and "3"
    // "1" -> "2" (1 is the left side of relationship; 2 is the right side)
    // "1" -> "3" (1 is the left side of relationship; 3 is the right side)

    // For "1" it will return "2" and "3"
    // For "2" it will return nothing
    // For "3" it will return nothing
    public virtual ICollection<RequestLinked> RequestsLinked { get; set; }

    // For "1" it will return nothing
    // For "2" it will return "1"
    // For "3" it will return "1"
    public virtual ICollection<RequestLinked> RequestsLinkedThisRequest { get; set; }
}
```

Mapping

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Request>()
        .HasKey(i => i.RequestID);

    modelBuilder.Entity<RequestLinked>()
        .HasKey(i => new {i.RequestID, i.RequestRelatedID });

    modelBuilder.Entity<Request>()
        .HasMany(i => i.RequestsLinked)
        .WithRequired(i => i.RequestRelated )
        .HasForeignKey(i => i.RequestRelatedID )
        .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

    modelBuilder.Entity<Request>()
        .HasMany(i => i.RequestsLinkedThisRequest )
        .WithRequired(i => i.Request)
        .HasForeignKey(i => i.RequestID)
        .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);


    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
}
```

See this link [Entity Framework - Fluent APi - Create table with 2 FK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31461173/entity-framework-fluent-api-create-table-with-2-fk/31465908#31465908) .

Hope it helps!

Comment: Can you give me some explanations on you solution please? Thanks anyway.

Comment: Take a look at the comments inside the code; that relationship fits in your situation?

Comment: Thanks I'll try that tomorrow and keep you in touch.

Comment: In that case, you have two navigation properties. The first one will return the cases which the current object is on the **left side** of the relationship. The second one  will return the cases which the current object is on the **right side** of the relationship. Take a look at the link in the end of the post. It might be useful.

Answer (score 0):

I think you model is good, but the nature of the problem is complex, I don't think there is an efficient LINQ query to retrieve the paths. Because retrieving the paths needs recursive moving left and right of the request. The best you can do is using SQL recursive queries I think. Something like this:

```
WITH cte AS ( 
            SELECT RequestLink.*, cast('(' + cast(RequestId as nvarchar(max)) + ',' 
                     + cast(RequestRelatedId as nvarchar(max))+')' as nvarchar(max)) Path 
              FROM RequestLink 
              WHERE RequestId = 3 OR RequestRelatedId = 3
              UNION ALL 

              SELECT a.*,
                   cast(
                         c.Path + '(' + 
                         cast(a.RequestId as nvarchar(max)) + ',' + 
                         cast(a.RequestRelatedId as nvarchar(max)) + ')' 
                       as nvarchar(max)
                       ) Path 
            FROM RequestLink a JOIN cte c ON 
                  a.RequestId = c.RequestRelatedId 
                  OR c.RequestId = a.RequestRelatedId 
                  OR c.RequestId = a.RequestId 
                  OR c.RequestRelatedId = a.RequestRelatedId 
                where c.Path not like cast(
                         '%(' + 
                         cast(a.RequestId as nvarchar(max)) + ',' + 
                         cast(a.RequestRelatedId as nvarchar(max)) + 
                         ')%' 
                       as nvarchar(max)
                       )

  )
  SELECT DISTINCT id from (
     SELECT distinct RequestId as id FROM cte
     union all 
     SELECT distinct RequestRelatedId as id FROM cte
  ) a
```

this query firstly finds the `id=3` then recursively appends the other links that have a common id with it and creates a path for it. The paths rows that are already in the path are discarded. Finally we `select` a `distinct` array of `id`s.[[a sample on fiddle]](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e6cac/1)
You can use this query in EF context as a function that calls `Database.SqlQuery(...)`.

One other option is to load all links to memory and construct a whole graph then find the paths using graph algorithms. This option can be used if the amount of links is small.

The other option is to add navigation property to the `Request` class as **Fabio Luz** post suggests, in this approach you can recursively navigate the two navigation properties and retrieve children, until you reach depth of `n`. Which `n` is the number of references.
You must be aware of **circular dependencies** in this approach, which can be overcame by keeping a list of traversed `Requests`. 
This approach needs many DB round trips(needs joins to retrieve navigation properties), so if the depth of paths is large this may not be an option.