# Entity Framework symetric many to many relation

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have DB entity `Item` which can be linked to other Items (same entities). The desired state is to have one collection on `Item` class:

```cs
public class Item
{
    public virtual ICollection<Item> LinkedItems { get; set; }
}
```

The relationship is symetric so if `itemA` is linked to `itemB` it automatically means that `itemB` is linked to `itemA`.

I have two following methods:

1. Have one `LinkedItems` property and every time add on both items:

   ```
   itemA.LinkedItems.Add(itemB);
   itemB.LinkedItems.Add(itemA);
   ```
2. Have two properties `LinkedItems1` and `LinkedItems2` and concat them every time:

   ```
   var linkedItems = itemA.LinkedItems.Concat(itemB.LinkedItems);
   ```

None of the above metods are ideal. Can it be done better (cleaner) way?

I am using EF Code First.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, `Item` should have 2 navigation properties. One for items that is linked, and another for items that is linked by.

```
public class Item
{
    public virtual ICollection<ItemAssociation> AssociatedItems { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ItemAssociation> ItemsAssociatedThisItem { get; set; }
}

public class ItemAssociation
{
    public int ItemId { get; set; }

    public int ItemAssociatedId { get; set; }

    public virtual Item Item { get; set; }

    public virtual Item ItemAssociated { get; set; }
}
```

Mapping:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<ItemAssociation>()
        .HasKey(i => new {i.ItemId , i.ItemAssociatedId });

    modelBuilder.Entity<Item>()
        .HasMany(i => i.AssociatedItems)
        .WithRequired(i => i.ItemAssociated)
        .HasForeignKey(i => i.ItemAssociatedId)
        .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

    modelBuilder.Entity<Item>()
        .HasMany(i => i.ItemsAssociatedThisItem )
        .WithRequired(i => i.Item)
        .HasForeignKey(i => i.ItemId)
        .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

When you want to retrieve all items related to a specific item, you get both collections, concat them and remove the repeated values.

**EDIT**

Mapping without association entity:

Class:

```
public class Item
{
    public int ItemId { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Item> AssociatedItems { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Item> ItemsAssociatedThisItem { get; set; }
}
```

Mapping:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Item>()
    .HasMany(i => i.AssociatedItems)
    .WithMany(i=> i.ItemsAssociatedThisItem)
    .Map(i =>
        {
            i.MapRightKey("ItemId");
            i.MapLeftKey("AssociatedItemId");
            i.ToTable("ItemsAssociation");
        });
```

Generated Migration:

```
CreateTable(
    "dbo.Items",
    c => new
        {
            ItemId = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
        })
    .PrimaryKey(t => t.ItemId);

CreateTable(
    "dbo.ItemsAssociation",
    c => new
        {
            AssociatedItemId = c.Int(nullable: false),
            ItemId = c.Int(nullable: false),
        })
    .PrimaryKey(t => new { t.AssociatedItemId, t.ItemId })
    .ForeignKey("dbo.Items", t => t.AssociatedItemId)
    .ForeignKey("dbo.Items", t => t.ItemId)
    .Index(t => t.AssociatedItemId)
    .Index(t => t.ItemId);
```

I think it is more clean now. Just change the names according to your style

Comment: Adding an association entity doesn't solve the problem at all, it makes it even more complicated I think.

Comment: An `Item` can be linked to more than one `Item`, right? Item A is linked to B and C. Item B is linked to D and A (because of the previous linking). So, I believe the only way you can accomplish this is using an association entity. In addition, to make the "reflexive relationship" the entity needs 2 collections... one for each case. Take a look at this thread, it might be helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31461173/entity-framework-fluent-api-create-table-with-2-fk/31465908#31465908

Comment: You are describing classical many to many relationship which I am familiar with. I presented use case where logically you need only one collection and the question was whether it can be done with EF with one collection.

And no, you don't have to have association entity for many to many relationships. EF can do this for you - of course there will be an association table in DB but it will be hidden in the model.

Comment: You can hide the "association entity", but you still must have 2 collections. I don't believe there is another way... However, I'm searching for this solution... maybe it could be possible using an interceptor. Overall, take a look at my edited answer, see if it is more clear now.